# Updating to MacOs Catalina make Apple script unable to export Pages Document: "Pages got an error: Invalid key form."

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-catalina

I am trying to update a Pages Apple Script to work on Catalina. This was working before the update but now this line fails:

```
set the targetExportFileHFSPath to "/Users/me/Desktop/tmp.pdf"
export thisDocument to file targetExportFileHFSPath as PDF <-- FAIL
```

Any idea why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'm surprised that worked before.  The `file` specifier rarely, if ever, qualifies a posix path (which is what you've got, not an HFS path as your variable name suggests).

Here are a few variations you can try:

```
set filepath to POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/tmp.pdf"
-- set filepath to POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/tmp.pdf" as alias
-- set filepath to "/Users/me/Desktop/tmp.pdf" as «class furl»
-- set filepath to "/Users/me/Desktop/tmp.pdf" as «class fsrf»
```

Then the **`export`** command in each case is simply:

```
export thisDocument to the filepath as PDF
```

Comment: That works, thanks, can you explain how you found that in the documentation? :)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for upvoting and ticking this answer. It's a bit awkward to say that I didn't look at the documentation (I don't currently have a working Mac, which is why I provided four variants instead of just one, as I wasn't in a position to test any of them first). I suppose I'm familiar with AppleScript to an extent that allows me to know roughly what it likes and what it doesn't like, and getting to grips with the various ways to reference a file in AppleScript was something I spent time doing in the beginning.

Comment: If you want to paste the definition of _Pages_' **`export`** command from its scripting dictionary, I'd be happy to add an addendum to my answer above to show you how to make sense of an application's scripting definition file if it's currently not seeming that helpful when you try to examine it yourself.

Comment: thanks, actually what doesn't make sense to me is where do I get the "extra" information. For example, yes, Export is defined, but where is it explained that you are supposed to use POSIX? I have updated my question with documentation screenshots. Thank you so much!

Comment: [Aliases and Files - _AppleScript Language Guide_](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28); and [Referencing Files and Folders - _Mac Automation Scripting Guide_](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH34-SW1)